# Save name and number of unknown people from Whatsapp Web

Tags: javascript, code-injection, whatsapp

I created an extension for Chrome that enable a Button in Whatsapp Web that, after click in some chatbox, the "zap.js" copy name + number from selected contact details.

https://github.com/defremont/zapbot

That because I need to save in Google Contacts, a big amount of unknown contacts that send me some text and previously, SAVE MY NUMBER ON YOUR CONTACTS.

To fully automate this I use "Mouse and Keyboard Recorder" to click in first contact and paste the information in some sheet.

https://github.com/LoranKloeze/WhatsAllApp

My program works this way currently because I could not create any function that clicks on the first contact in the list.

I've seen extensions that creates something like a unknown contact store (WLAPStore).. however I did not understand how it was done.

https://github.com/LoranKloeze/WhatsAllApp/blob/master/ui.js

The question is: Is there a way to click on the contact automatically? I have already tried `querySelector` with `onClick` and others similar. Anything.

- Button activated
  [image]

---

- Information auto copied
  [image]

---

- Information manually pasted in google contacts sheet
  [image]